# Wordpress thumbnail post after latest update not working with facebook share

Tags: facebook, wordpress

**in WordPress version 3.8** 
while sharing post on facebook it was looking like 
[image: post display on facebook]

**in WordPress version 3.9 there is no images, no proper linking** 
[image: Wordpress 3.9 this is showing]

I am sharing my wordpress blog link http://engineerbabu.com/2014/04/founder-who-can-help-you/ try to share same in facebook you will get same error.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your URL through the Facebook Debug tool and it now works. Basically it looks like there was a bad cached version within Facebook and the debug tool broke that cache. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: After testing url from facebook debug tools this works well. 
Check new url of same site  http://engineerbabu.com/2014/04/100-reasons-to-love-android/ in facebook than try debug tool this will work well.